# Constructor or main()? How do I pass in perameters to the method?

Tags: java

I am confusing myself more and more and I have nobody to ask about this. I am home alone, studying for exams and have been starting at this for a while. I'm a novice at Java. Please can anyone tell me if i'm on the right track with my attempt (at the end).

I want to ask if I should include a constructor here in this class or if I should include the main method (and make it the application class), also I want to know how to pass the 99 miles into the method. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you.

**Question**:

The DistanceConversion class is listed in Appendix A. The purpose of this class is to convert a distance specified in miles to kilometres and vice versa. Develop a class that uses an instance of the DistanceConversion class to perform the following conversions:

(i)   Convert 99 miles to kilometres
  (ii)  Convert 76 kilometers to miles

And displays the results of each conversion on screen.

Clearly show how each of the methods of the DistanceConversion class are invoked within your class to perform these conversions.

**Appendix A:**

```
class DistanceConversion {
  private double miles;
  private double kilometres; 

  public DistanceConversion(){
    miles = 0;
    kilometres = 0;
  }

  public void setMiles(double m){
    miles = m;
  }

  public double getMiles(){
    return miles;
  }

  public void setKilometers(double k){
    kilometres = k;
  }

  public double getKilometers(){
    return kilometres;
  }

  public void convertMilesToKilometers(){
    kilometres = miles * (8/5);
  }

  public void convertKilometersToMiles(){
    miles = kilometres * (5/8);
  }
}
```

**My attempt so far:**

```
public class Convert {

    //private int miles = 99;
   //private int kilometers = 76;

    public static void main(String args[]){

    public Convert(){   
    }

    DistanceConversion myConverter = new DistanceConversion();

    myConverter.convertMilesToKilometers();


    }
}
```

Comment: Unless it was a typo, I suggest not including a constructor within the main method.

Comment: I think the downvotes here are a bit harsh, especially without any comments to explain how the question could have been improved. Don't be put off, @Hairdo, I'd say this is exactly the right way to ask for help on a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

No. All you need is a main method that

- creates an instance of DistanceConversion
- sets its miles, converts them to kilometers, gets the kilometers and print them
- then sets its kilometers, converts them to miles, get the miles and print them

You don't need any constructor or field to do that. Everything should be in the main method.

Side note: this DistanceConversion class is extremely badly designed. You can do nothing about it, of course, but I feel like it's my duty to say it.

Comment: Heh, I was thinking the same about the `DistanceConversion` class - looks like code written by a professor who's never actually worked outside academia, but don't tell him that, @Hairdo... :D

Comment: I agree, its a wonky design.  I was thinking it was maybe to make them use accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, use parameterized constructors when creating a new instance of the object, with the values already populated, and setters when changing the values of a field after the object has been created. Constructor approach has been answered.You can also write something like this in the main method:

```
public class Convert {

    private int miles = 99;
   //private int kilometers = 76;

    public static void main(String args[]){
      DistanceConversion myConverter = new DistanceConversion();
      myConverter.setMiles(99);
      myConverter.convertMilesToKilometers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you certainly are on the right lines to me. I think you need to use the `setKilometres()` and `setMiles()` methods, which will set the `kilometres` and `miles` fields in `DistanceConversion`.

Once you've done that, you'll find that the `convert...` methods should give you the correct results.

Comment: You'll also need to output the results. I assume you've encountered `System.out.println()` before, but if not, I assume that's what the assignment is expecting you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a constructor which receives the number of miles you want to convert as an argument. For example:

```
public DistanceConversion(double milesToConvert){

    miles = milesToConvert;
    kilometres = 0;
}
```

Next, in main(), create a new instance of DistanceConversion:

```
DistanceConversion myConverter = new DistanceConversion(99);
```

After that, invoke conversion method and display conversion result via System.out.println method.

```
myConverter.convertMilesToKilometers();
System.out.println("In kilometers: " + myConverter.getKilometers());
```